# Unique Column in WSS 3.0 List

Tags: list, sharepoint, wss-3.0

I am trying to implement a feature in a list from WSS3.0.
Basically I have a list and I want to add items to the list but I want to check first if there is already any item with the same value in a specific column.

I have a column named "My Key Field" and I want the values in this field to be unique. So, for example, if I have a record in the list where "My Key Field=65 210" I should not be able to add a new item when a users inserts the same value for the "My Key Field".

Any ideas on how to do this? A simple solution would be great considering my lack of skills concerning to Sharepoint programming....but I am flexible and I can learn.

Thanks for your attention!

Regards,
Aganju

Answer (score 0):

The SPServices library has a method for this, called [SPRequireUnique](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPRequireUnique&referringTitle=Documentation). It relies on SharePoint Web services.

For the record, you get this feature out of the box in SP 2010.